# Override Angular predefined date format

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a multilingual Angular 11 app.

I want to change the `short` predefined format for `en-US` from the default `M/d/yy, h:mm a` into a format with a **4-digit year**. For all other locales it should stay as it is. Is it somehow possible to do without needing to specify the format in every DatePipe invocation or extending DatePipe?

(On a side note, I find it a really weird decision by Angular to make a 2-digit year the default for English, because for other locales it's 4 digits for the same `short` format.)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just defining `short`, be more verbose with it and it'll work.

Example: `{{today | date : 'M/d/yyyy, h:mm a' }}`

Stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-hcdrss?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

All the supported date format syntax can be found [here](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)

Comment: He asked how to manage the date format according to the current language used in the app, not how to change formats by general

Comment: Exactly. The question is about one specific locale.

Comment: I misunderstood. Doing by locale is probably not possible out of the box. I would just make your own date pipe implementation that accounts for the locale. I suppose you could take a poor mans route and just do an `*ngIf` and call it a day as well.